# How to place a delimiter in a NetworkStream byte array?

Tags: c#, .net, networkstream

I'm setting up a way to communicate between a server and a client.  How I am working it at the moment, is that a stream's first byte will contain an indicator of what is coming and then looking up that request's class I can determine the length of the request:

```
stream.Read(message, 0, 1)

if(message == <byte representation of a known class>)
{
    stream.Read(message, 0, Class.RequestSize);
}
```

I'm curious how to handle the case of when the class size is not known, of if after reading a known request the data is corrupt.

I'm thinking that I can insert in some sort of delimiter into the stream, but since a byte can only be between 0-255, I'm not sure how to go about creating a unique delimiter.  Do I want to place a pattern into the stream to represent the end of a message?  How can I be sure that this pattern is unique enough to not be mistaken for actual data?

Comment: Split your stream in fixed size **chunks** (let's say, for example, 64K). Prepend 2 bytes to each chunk with the current size, when you'll receive a chunk where this value is not 0xFFFF then you reached the end of the stream. Do not try to have an unique pattern, it's **sure it'll be broken** unless you encode your input data (but that will make them bigger).

Comment: @Adriano with your approach how would I prevent someone from sending 0xFFFF sizes till the end of time?

Comment: If sender is malicious no, you can't (unless you set an arbitrary limit). But if you can receive an extra counter (before the first chunk) with the number of chunks that will be send (this will limit the maximum size too). However I would consider twice to add or not this kind of check for data integrity. This kind of stuffs are handled at lower level **by the protocol** (are you using a TCP connection?).

Comment: I am using the TcpClient class at the moment.  I'm just trying to figure out how to flush out a bad stream and try to get to the next one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are different approaches on this. One option would be sending the length of the class name and possible of the whole packet first (e.g. always the first byte). This way you can read just read that byte and then n bytes more to get the class name.

By this approach you don't end up reading a *lot* of stuff a malicious client sends you with the intent to DoS your application and you can quickly determine if you read enough to handle the packet or if it's not yet complete.

Answer (score 0):

There are some low level bytes which are used especially as delimiters. Start of Text and End of Text have a (hex) value of 0x02 and 0x03 respectively. And you have Start of Heading coupled with End of Transmission, 0x01 and 0x04; you could use these.

Comment: Only if it's guaranteed that his data never contains those characters. If he's dealing with binary data that's not the case.

Comment: Well sure, but that depends on his data, I think it's okay to at least mention this.